# (click) broken inside *ngFor on elements of type array if coming from a function

Tags: angular

in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EDnnx8agUy5dWFA98TlD?p=preview) I've reproduced a strange edge case. It probably depends on pixijs or perhaps on webgl as it happens when using pixijs.

Notice how you can click on all the elements of the lists but as soon as you start using pixijs (just click on the button) the click stop working on the element of type array. The **odd** thing is that it still works on all the other elements. It is **even odder** that if instead of using a function to return an array, it is used an inline array, all works as expected...

any ideas ?

**app.component.ts**

```ts
<button *ngIf="!renderer" (click)="breakIt()">break me</button> 
<span *ngIf="renderer">BROKEN</span>
Clicked: {{clicked | json}}

<h2>It breaks</h2>
<h3 *ngFor="#n of ns()" (click)="click(n)">{{n | json}}</h3>

<h2>It works</h2>
<h3 *ngFor="#n of [[2,4],'ciao',4,true]" (click)="click(n)">{{n | json}}</h3>
```

**app.component.html**

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  clicked = "";
  renderer;

  breakIt() {
    this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(200, 200,{backgroundColor : 0x1099bb});
  }

  ns() {
    return [[2,4],'ciao',4,true];
  }

  click(n) {
    this.clicked=n;  
  }
}
```

Comment: `ns()` violates the [idempotent rule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#idempotence).

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused by

```ts
  ns() {
    return [[2,4],'ciao',4,true];
  }
```

and

```ts
<h3 *ngFor="#n of ns()"
```

With every event Angular invokes change detection and each time it checks whether the previously returned value from `ns()` is the same as the current one it turns out to be different every time, because each call to `ns()` returns a new array. Angular expects the model to stabilize.

Angular doesn't compare properties or the contents of objects and arrays, it only does identity checks and `ns()` for every call returns a new and thus different array instance.

Instead it should be

```ts
  var arr = [[2,4],'ciao',4,true]; 
  ns() {
    return this.arr;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, you are getting infinite change loop. I happens because each time you return new array from `ns()` AND `PIXI.autoDetectRenderer` somehow triggers angular change event.

Tried to set changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush - it works. So i guess angular detects periodic changes in renderer object and starts processing changes and can not stop since every time template value != ns() method result.

Comment: I guess that PIXI.autoDetectRenderer has a ticker (Timeout) 60 times a second which would cause a change event and that would explain why the page is continuously rerendered. But that doesn't explain why the click event is not working **only*** for those "array of array" returned by the function.

Comment: Method returns **new** array each time, so every 1/60s angular calls `ns()` to get its value to compare with current template value(previously returned by ns() method), but obviously values are not strictly equal, they are different objects.