# Angular2 click event not firing

Tags: events, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement custom pagination component. This is template.

```html
<div *ngIf="totalItems != 0">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li *ngFor="let page of pages" [ngClass]="{'active': currentPage == page.title}">
            <a (click)="changePage(page)">{{page.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <select>
        <option *ngFor="let size of pageSizes">{{size}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pager',
    templateUrl: 'templates/pager.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['styles/pager.component.css']
})
export class PagerComponent {
    @Input() totalItems: number = 0;
    @Input() lastText: string = "»";
    @Input() firstText: string = "«";
    @Input() nextText: string = "›";
    @Input() prevText: string = "‹";
    public currentPage: number = 1;
    pageSizes: Array<number> = [10, 15, 30];
    public currentSize: number = this.pageSizes[0];

    @Output() pageChanged = new EventEmitter();

    get pages(): Array<IPage> {
        var list = new Array<IPage>();
        let pageCount = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.currentSize);
        let start = Math.max(this.currentPage - 1, 1);
        let end = Math.min(this.currentPage + 2, pageCount);
        list.push({ title: this.firstText, number: 1 });
        list.push({ title: this.prevText, number: this.currentPage - 1});
        for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            list.push({ title: String(i), number: i });
        }
        list.push({ title: this.nextText, number: this.currentPage + 1});
        list.push({ title: this.lastText, number: end});
        return list;
    }

    public changePage(page: IPage) {
        this.currentPage = page.number;
        this.pageChanged.emit(null);
    };

    public resetCurrentPage(): void {
        this.currentPage = 1;
    }
}
```

I was using simple array of numbers. Then I wanted to add Last/Firts buttons. I wrote interface that contains two properties title and page number. Now click event doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: @galvan there's no any error. @Günter Zöchbauer it ins't firing. I've tried to create custom `<div>` and bind the same function on `click` It works good with `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it! It's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586050/click-broken-inside-ngfor-on-elements-of-type-array-if-coming-from-a-function). It generated new array each time. So angular can't bind an event to array item.
@Günter Zöchbauer, it should be familiar to you.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Would be great if you could tell how did you solved it?

Comment: I can't remember details of implementation, just try to save an array in your class field and return it in a property. Please, see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is function changePage() has an argument of type IPage and you pass a number

```
 public changePage(page: IPage) {
    this.currentPage = page.number;
    this.pageChanged.emit(null);
};
```

change it to

```
 public changePage(num: number) {
    this.currentPage = num;
    this.pageChanged.emit(null);
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change the template. And it doesn't work this way as well.